# How to add style bullets to Summary Links Web Part

Tags: web-part

I am working with Summary Links Web Part and I notice that when I click on Configure Styles and Layouts that in the dropdown the selection is different from one Site Collection to another.

My question is, is there a way to add a style selection to the dropdown?

For a better explanation please see below:

[image]

Based on the above, is there a way for me to add a bullet style for example, something called SmallBullet to the dropdown list in Summary Links Web Part?

I heard it was possible but I have not seen it performed.

Comment: Any other options? My bullets are present in the summary links settings and when I "save" the page, but disappear when I "check in". Tried the above using both content editor and script editor without success. SharePoint Online (Office 365)

Answer (score 0):

I think creating your own custom Style Sheets can fix that. For a more quick fix you can add a Content Editor web part and use the following CSS to add Bullets to your Summary Links.

```
<style>
.cbq-layout-main A:before {
    CONTENT: " \2022 "
}
</style>
```